# Error when running a python3 Xcode project (Too many levels of symbolic links and Operation not permitted) - macOS BigSur

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode, macos, macos-big-sur

I recently bought a new computer (I am completely new with macOS):

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
- Puce Apple M1
- macOS Big Sur version 11.1

I would like to set-up a **python3** development environment in **Xcode**.

I followed the following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUBGoeCu19I) on the web.

I set up the project interpreter to Python3.

However, when I click on the **play button** (run), I get an error:

> 2021-01-09 12:17:40.062440+0100 python3[1139:27278] Failed to open
> macho file at
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 for
> reading: Too many levels of symbolic links
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: can't open
> file 'PythonTest.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
>
> Program ended with exit code: 2

I also tried to execute python3 code in the cmd, its working well.
So the problem seems to come from Xcode.

Moreover, I observed in my Xcode project that I can **select** among three propositions:

- apple Silicon
- apple Silicon (arm64)
- apple Rosetta

What is the **difference** among them (in terms of python execution) ?
Knowing that the error appears for each of the previous options.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, remember that it is better to explain what you try to do rather than asking people to follow the link to a youtube tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to modify the path of the python bin.
Go to Edit Scheme set the Executable to

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

The best step by step description I found on how to setup a python project in Xcode was here (in chinese): https://blog.csdn.net/qq_15289761/article/details/107082908